# Why is SFTP fingerprint from FileZilla not accepted by WinSCP .NET assembly in C#?

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, filezilla, winscp-net

I'm setting up to put files using SFTP to a client's server.  I have an SFTP server to test and developed a client using WinSCP in C# VS2022 on Windows Server 2019.  I initially logged on to the test server using FileZilla and copied the fingerprint by double clicking it.  I pasted that into my C# client and it worked as expected.

I did the very same thing with the client's SFTP server, but I get the error: *"SSH host key fingerprint does not match pattern"*.  The format does look slightly different from mine:

```
SHA256:tUlL3I72i+NOA.......DLTVoH35szgNVJiOGGhRV/ic
```

Mine has SHA256 [space] then the footprint.  I'm not sure what the `:tUlL3I72i+` is all about but I've tried removing it, turning the `+` into a space, etc. but same error.

What am I missing and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileZilla's *Unknown host key* box looks like this:

[image]

In WinSCP .NET assembly, that maps to the following value of [`Session.SshHostKeyFingerprint`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshhostkeyfingerprint):

```
"ssh-ed25519 255 1hI1HqP3IzoOWCABHGS7+GsrP2JUVsSs7oskK7HGP1E"
```

---

Though way easier is to [use WinSCP GUI to generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you:

[image]